# How to open Minecraft systemd service server console on CentOS 8?

Tags: centos, gnu-screen, java, minecraft

I'm pretty new to Linux and because of that this might be a stupid question but anyways:
I've made a CentOS 8 virtual machine on my computer to run a Minecraft server for me and my friends using [this guide.](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-minecraft-server-on-centos-7/) So if I understood correctly I made another linux user for the server and the server starts as a systemd service everytime I power on the machine.

It's convenient that the server starts automatically but there's one problem with that, I cannot use the server console. Only way to use the console I found was to use a screen session for the service but as I'm new to using Linux, I have no idea how to do that (I need to add something to the minecraft.service file?).
My minecraft.service file below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=minecraft
Nice=1
KillMode=none
SuccessExitStatus=0 1
ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full
PrivateDevices=true
NoNewPrivileges=true
WorkingDirectory=/opt/minecraft/server
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui
ExecStop=/opt/minecraft/tools/mcrcon/mcrcon -H 127.0.0.1 -P 25575 -p mypassword stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So anyways my question would be that how would I run the server with screen feature or is there some better way?

Comment: There is a multitude of screen questions. I would write a small script just to simplify the exec line of that service file, and inside create a new detached screen session if it doesn't already exist that runs the minecraft server inside. Then you can access with `screen -x your-screen-name-or-pid`

Answer (score 1):

Change the startup instruction in your `minecraft.service` from:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui
```

to:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -DmS minecraft-screen /usr/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui
```

`minecraft-screen` is just a name for the screen, you can change this into whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

To preface this, I don't personally host minecraft servers. I just helped a friend of mine make his server into a systemd service.

You'll want to enable RCON in your server's config (Which I'm guessing you have already) and then you can use mcrcon from your terminal to connect to your server after it has started.

```
mcrcon -h <ip> -P <port> -t
```

This should give you the live terminal(-t) you would normally see when you run the server not as a service.

Some additional clarification for your use case since you mentioned being new to linux:

The command mcrcon may not be in your PATH variable already. So if you go to run the syntax in the above code block, it may give you an error stating that no such command is found. If that is the case, to preserve the functionality of your service file, you should symbolically link
/opt/minecraft/tools/mcrcon/mcrcon (the path to your mcrcon executable) to a location which is already in PATH such as /usr/bin

```
ln -s /opt/minecraft/tools/mcrcon/mcrcon /usr/bin/mcrcon
```

This will allow you to run mcrcon from any working directory, rather than having to change directories to /opt/minecraft/tools/mcrcon/ and run it as ./mcrcon or using the full path /opt/minecraft/tools/mcrcon/mcrcon to run mcrcon.

**EDIT**

Your normal STDOUT log messages that you can no longer see when you use RCON should still be logged to server.log, in your logs subdirectory within your minecraft server directory.

Comment: By doing this I could write commands and stuff to the console, but what I'm searching for is that I could see the console logs etc. live. If I run the server regularly using java command, I can see the console logs live from the terminal. But now when I run the server as a systemd service, I cannot see the logs from anywhere. Only way to connect to the server that I found was RCON, and that doesn't show logs. It's kind of hard to explain.

Comment: Does it save logs to /var/log? Usually system apps save logs there.

Comment: Unfortunately by default it will not log to /var/log. It should log to <minecraft directory>/logs/server.log.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add

```
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

To the section [Service]

in CentOS the service should be placed in /etc/systemd/system

So you should create a file minecraft_server.service inside the mentioned directory with the content you provided in your post.

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft Server
After=network.target

[Service]
User=minecraft
Nice=1
KillMode=none
SuccessExitStatus=0 1
ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full
PrivateDevices=true
NoNewPrivileges=true
WorkingDirectory=/opt/minecraft/server
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui
ExecStop=/opt/minecraft/tools/mcrcon/mcrcon -H 127.0.0.1 -P 25575 -p mypassword stop
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then perform a command:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Which is needed when you add a new service.

Then type command:

```
sudo systemctl start minecraft_server.service
```

If you want the service to start during server boot, just enable it:

```
sudo systemctl enable minecraft_server.service
```

Instaed start you can use also stop and restart, to stop or restart the service.

I did not play Minecraft and will never do, I am not familiar with it. I just know how to add a service in systemd.

This website explains how to use systemctl.
[How To Use Systemctl to Manage Systemd Services and Units](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units)

Comment: I have no idea who downvoted this, but the move is really stupid. It explains exactly how to add a new service into the system. The answer is useful, but needs knowledge and understanding. This is not for a newbie. We should not help people with knowledge from leaves wheen they do not understand the roots.